# Enable Full SSL for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wp-config, ssl, https

I've enabled SSL for my main domain but i want to enable it fully for my wordpress website which is located in a subfolder. when i say fully i mean in admin area and the website itself and without any mixed content error.

so first i tried adding these in wp-config:

```
/* Enable SSL Encryption */
define(‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’, true);
define(‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’, true);
```

it resulted in getting mixed content error and "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" error after login to the dashboard. i got the same error when i tried to change the blog url and website url in settings. then i used plugins like "https-ssl", "fix mixed content". they didn't do anything good for me either. i'm looking for a way to make that happen

Comment: In the options did you set the blog URL and home URL to `https://...` too?

Comment: yes i forgot to mention that, after that i got the same error that said "you do not have sufficient permissions". then i used phpmyadmin to access the database to change those addresses back to http version

Comment: After changing it to SSL, try to clear your cookies and then log in again. You won't be able to access the new SSL pages with your old auth cookies.

Comment: i did that but no luck. the website loads over https but i get this error all over the browser console "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by moving the two define statements up before the require_once that includes wp-settings.php. Seems this was the issue all along.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193576/117268

Comment: I had found another workaround for that but i just tested your method on an offline example and so far it works very well, i will use it online too, thank you!

Comment: This saved me from another 4 hours of debugging. Thank you!